# Slimscroll doesn't work with mouse wheel in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, fullpage.js, slimscroll

I'm using both jQuery plugins:
-fullpage
-slimscroll

for the purposes of making the scrollOverflow option work, so that I can scroll inside the sections with large content, and AFAIK, this happens in Internet Explorer 11.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors:['home', 'what-we-do', 'our-work', 'contact-us'],
        menu: '#menu',
        css3: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 1000,
        scrollBar: true,
        scrollOverflow: true, ...
```

Works fine in Internet Explorer, except when the slimscroll is activated in smaller screens.

Whenever I try to use the mousewheel to scroll down in a section with slimscroll activated, it won't work. Instead I can go back to the previous section by scrolling up.

### [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zyxcw7Lg/2/)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [this topic in fullPage.js forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1032).

> scrollOverflow:true was never tested with scrollBar:true as it doesn't make much sense to have two scroll bars.
>
> ...
>
> Therefore I don't think this problem will get solved.

Try preventing the use of double scroll bars. From he UI point of view its a terrible thing.

Comment: I got rid of the main scrollbar with `body{overflow: hidden;}` but the issue is still there in IE. Perhaps I didn't get rid of it completely?

Comment: @Fabián you can not just do that... the issue is not the scroll bar itself, is the way the plugin deal with your site if you use it. Use the option `scrollBar:false` instead.

Comment: I'll try. btw you repeated "scrollOverflow:true" twice... In the end you meant "scrollOverflow:true was never tested with scrollBar:true"... right?